# Expression modules error 'filter object'

Tags: python, regex

I'm learning expression modules and was at this website 
http://www.thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/module_re.html

I did the first exercise in 9.1

```
s = ['airplane', 'base', 'ALLIGATOR', 'Broad' ]

filter((lambda x: re.match(r'A', x)),s)
```

Answer is `['ALLIGATOR']`

but I get

```
<filter object at 0x102c36550>
```

as my answer not `['ALLIGATOR']`

I am using Python 3.4.2
Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: my answer is '<filter object at 0x102c36550'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [**documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

> Construct an iterator from those elements of iterable for which function returns true. iterable may be either a sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.
>
> Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator expression `(item for item in iterable if function(item))` if function is not None and `(item for item in iterable if item)` if function is None.

To get thoses elements you need a loop or use `next`

```
>>> next(filter(lambda x: re.match(r'A', x), s))
'ALLIGATOR'
```

or

```
 >>> [word for word in filter(lambda x: re.match(r'A', x), s)]
 ['ALLIGATOR']
```